# Swift: How to set dynamic cell height in TableViewController which contains more than one cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableViewController, which contains three different customized cell. For the first cell, I want to contain a horizontal scrolled CollectionView, the second cell contains a CollectionView as well, and the third one contains a vertical CollectionView. I write my code like this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell1") as! HomePageTableViewCell1


        return cell
    }

     else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell2") as! HomePageTableViewCell2


        return cell
    }
     else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell3") as! HomePageTableViewCell3


        return cell
    }

}
```

it works like I want, but I am not sure is this the best way to achieve what I want? cause I am new to Swift, maybe there are some better way to do this?

Secondly, for these three cell, I want to retain dynamic height based one the content. for example, the first cell contains a ImageView which height is 260, the second cell contains a ImageView with 140 of the height. the third cell contains a CollectionView which will return 4 rows, and in each row, there is a ImageView with height 96. what I have done is :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
         return 260
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return 140
    }
    else {
        return 500

    }
}
```

but this means I have to hard code these height in the case I know the height of the content. But what if I don't know the height, like if the third cell will return 5 row, which means 500 is not enough, then what should I do to give the cell a dynamic height.

Comment: use heightforRowAtIndexPath for setting each cell height

Comment: how to identify each cell? use `indexPath.section` ?

Comment: yea using indexpath.section == 0 like this , best way to manage Height of Each cell

Comment: I guess this is what I am doing in the code above, right?

Comment: Yea but along it , either handle it using constriant or manage height of content by finding height of each content .

Comment: sorry I didn't get your meaning. For example the third cell, which contains a `UICollectionView`, and this collection view contains reusable cell, maybe 5, maybe 6. how to adjust the height for the `TableViewCell` based on the `numberOfItemAtIndexPath` return by the `CollectionView`? of cause each `CollectionViewCell` 's height is set. thanks

Comment: Once go through this link , very well explained how to handle self resizing cell either in collectionview or tableview , here is link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell1") as! HomePageTableViewCell1

        let string1 = "blablabla"
        let charCountString1 = string1.character.characters.count

        tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(charCountString1)
        return cell
    }

     else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell2") as! HomePageTableViewCell2

        let imageHeight = imageView.frame.height

        tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(imageHeight)
        return cell
    }
     else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell3") as! HomePageTableViewCell3

        let string3 = "ldsakjfalksdjflk"
        let charCountString3 = string3.character.characters.count

        tableView.rowHeight = CGFloat(charCountString3)
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: so I can set the height inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, thats good. but the `50, 100,150` is set based on the need right? so for my case, it will be `260, 140, 500` right? But I want dynamic cell height, how can I do that? thanks

Comment: Yea you can feel 50, 100, 150 with whatever values you want. These values can be build up dynamically, I'll adjust the the example to demonstrate. Get the idea?

Comment: I see. But how about when the cell is return `ImageView` rather than `string`? thanks

Comment: I think you might want to add some height constraints to your image view, not? If not you can get the height of your ImageView and set that as the height of your row. I'll do it for section 1 in the example.

Comment: yes, I want. for ImageView I definitely need to set the constrains. How about the third cell, which contains a `UICollectionView`, and this collection view contains reusable cell, maybe 5, maybe 6. how to adjust the height for the `TableViewCell` based on the `numberOfItemAtIndexPath` return by the `CollectionView`? of cause each `CollectionViewCell` 's height is set. thanks

Comment: I think it's best to post a new question for that. Deviating too much from the original post.

Comment: thats what I asked in my question, how to return dynamic height of `TableViewCell` which contains more than one cell.

Comment: Count the number of items in the array that you're using to build up the CollectionView. This will result in the number of CollectionViewCells. Use this integer to set that TableView row's height.

Comment: I see. I got the idea, I will have a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can always have the dynamic height for your tableView on the base of your content, no need to return the static height for just setup the constraints in your cell properly and always use preferred priority for content-hugging content-compressionResistance.

in -viewDidLoad
just set

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60; // or whatever is suitable for you
```

you can also have reference from the Ray Wenderlich's tutorial 
[Self-sizing Table View Cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look